# How to remove the transparency of top Bar on IOS App swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a Web View app. Main Problem I am facing is when I scroll the page, Content is visible on top bar where Battery, Signal and time is mentioned.
[image]

This is really weird.

[image]

What I have done but not getting the luck

```
info.plist ->
add row -> View Controller-based-status bar appearance -> Set NO
```

Also tried many things but not getting success. Is there anyone who can guide me hoe to solve this.

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated.

> QUESTION UPDATE:

I added on ViewController.swift under loadView Function:

```
let containerViewHeight: CGFloat = 45

webView = WKWebView()//(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width:screenWidth, height:screenHeight))
view.addSubview(webView)

webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -containerViewHeight).isActive = true

containerView = WKWebView()//(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width:screenWidth, height:screenHeight))
view.addSubview(containerView)

containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
```

By this My issue will Resolved. But on footer bar there is a space created. I attached the image for reference.

[image]

Can Anyone guide me how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you auto layout your web view to safe area?

Comment: @Asif No. Will you tell me how to do this?

Comment: I add this as an answer, please take a look at that

Comment: set your webView top constraints to View, not to safe Area. @Aks

Answer (score 0):

Like below image select your web view in storyboard. then add these 4 constraints to 0. then press “Add 4 constraints”

[image]

For more about autolayout: [Auto layout tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/443-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started)

Comment: I did this at the starting Time. Can you tell me how will I open this View. I am not able to open this.

Comment: Right click on your .storyboard file then select:  "open as" then select "interface builder storyboard"

Comment: Add new Constraints is completely disabled. I click on it but nothing happen as it looks faded which is disabled. Nopt able to add 0 to all Boxes

Comment: Fisrt select your webview by one click on that webview , then try to add constraints

Comment: I added my answer to question. Can you help me out regarding this?